# Google App engine auto update

Tags: google-app-engine, installation, windows-installer

Google App Engine always wants me to download and install software when new version released.

Any option to do this task automatically ? 
Why they are not implement the software auto updation ?

Comment: AppEngine doesn't update all that often. Is it really such a burden to you to download the SDK and isntall it?

Comment: I use mercurial for version control and would like to be able to checkout a latest version and both my project and the sdk in one combined clone but now my project's solution is downloading the SDK and downloading my project via version control, it could be easier merging the steps to 1 so that updating your project via googlecode or git also updates to latest SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Not *really* a programming related question.

People do not want their SDKs randomly updating without telling you, APIs change over time and you might not be ready.